# SAS I want to use an iteration variable to declare variables on a data set

Tags: sas

I want to use `i` to be part of a defining variable like var_1,var_2,.....var_16
also if i have Rate1,Rate2,....Rate15

**How can i do that to:**

Have this var_1=Rate1(substitue by its value 1)

```
 Data s;
      format Sr var_1-var_16 ;
      Rate1=1;
      Rate2=2;
 do i=1 to 15 by 1;
            var_i=Ratei;
   end;
run;
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. SAS data sets cannot contain arrays; they only have variables. What are the variables in your data set?

Answer (score 2):

This is my best guess as to what you're asking: You have 16 variables, `var_1, ..., var_16` and you want to assign each of their values to another set of variables `Rate1, ..., Rate16`.

This will work:

```
data s;
  array var{*} var_1-var_16;
  array Rate{16};

  do i=1 to 15;
    Rate{i} = var{i};
  end;
 drop i;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method that uses macros. Personally I find parsing the %'s easier than working with arrays, but that's just me.

```
%macro foo;
data s;
  %do i = 1 %to 16;
  var_&i = rate&i;
  %end;
run;
%mend;

%foo
```

Comment: Don't use macros when there's no need. Arrays aren't difficult to learn or use, cleaner than macro code any day.

Comment: I didn't say they were difficult to learn or use. I just find them a rather clunky way of doing quasi-column-indexing compared to other languages.